# Como estilizar ícone de calendário em HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Eu tenho um input do HTML5 com o `type="date"`,  dessa forma:

```html
<input type="date">
```

Existe alguma forma de mudar a cor do ícone de calendário que ele traz nativamente? Já tentei propriedades como `-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` mas não muda a cor do ícone, apenas a fonte ou o background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **OBS**: A solução abaixo não funciona no navegador Firefox. Verifiquem compatibilidade em outros navegadores para esta solução. Os testes foram feitos e funcionaram nos navegadores Google Chrome e Brave.

<sup>Agradeçendo ao @GuilhermeNascimento pela comentário de observação :)</sup>

---

Existe uma possibilidade de se usar o [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()_2) e alterar as cores do ícone em questão.

Esta resposta tem como base [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162645/change-color-of-chromes-calendar-icon-in-html-date-input) e [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters) pergunta e no SOen, que permite você fazer um combinações usando `filter` e propriedades como `invert`, `sepia`, `saturate`, `brightness` e `hue-rotate`. No exemplo abaixo, alterando os valores de `hue-rotate`, pode resultar em cores distintas.

Exemplos:

- Para o `hue-rotate(20deg)`, teremos uma cor avermelhada:

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: invert(0.8) brightness(50%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

- Para o `hue-rotate(240deg)`, teremos uma cor azulada para o ícone:

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: invert(0.8) brightness(50%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(240deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Você ainda pode gerar diferente combinacões alterando as propriedades [`invert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert()), [`sepia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/sepia()), [`saturate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/saturate()), [`brightness`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness()) e [`hue-rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate()).

Comment: Note que isso funciona em Chrome e provavelmente no Safari, mas não funciona em Firefox, claro que no Firefox não tem o tal ícone, então a solução aplicada para Chromium/Webklit funcionará bem. Portanto deixo o +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, mas como ele usou o webkit, achei que o AP já possa estaria ciente disso. Mas acho que vale a pena destacar a sua observacão na resposta.

Comment: Tem prefixos webkit que funcionam em Firefox ([porque questões "históricas"](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/09/firefox-49-fixes-sites-designed-with-webkit-in-mind-and-more/)). Por isso é sempre bom detalhar algumas coisas :)